# Tikz-bug? overlap of arrow parts

Tags: tikz-pgf

when using arrows with Triangle Caps, tikz draws the part surrounding the junction between the line and the tip twice. This leads to unwanted results when using opacity; in addition, the part appended to the tip is not bendable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikz { 
    \draw [line width=10mm,opacity=0.5,-{Triangle Cap[]}] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw [line width=7mm,opacity=0.5,-{Triangle Cap[]}] (0,1)
                                .. controls (1.5,0.5) and (1,4) .. (2,4);
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: buggy arrows]

Any thoughts, solutions?

Thanks in advance!

uzahnd

Comment: Hi uzahnd, welcome to the site! To fix this issue, wrap your arrow in `\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5] ... \end{scope}`

Comment: Ok, thanks, this solves the opacity issue - but not the bending problem.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. It would be best if you could open a new question for this, since that's really independent of the opacity issue. This site works best if each question contains only a single independent issue, since that makes it much easier for others with similar problems to find the question.